# RGB data sent from python program not recieving right by arduino

Tags: python, colors, arduino, rgb

I am working on a twitter mood light and have arduino and python code. After losing all my python code, it had to remake it from memory, but i had some problems. The python code is sending rgb data to the arduino to change an rgb led's color. For some reason though, the arduino is not picking up the last value and is changing the second value to the blue led.

For example: I sent 50,50,50 which is a dim white, and the led shows purple (blue and red) and if i send 0,0,255 (blue on) it stays blank and if i send 0,255,0 (green on) it shows blue.

I have no idea have have tried so many things to get it to work.

Python code:
I know i am sending the data twice it is the only way the send function works

```
from __future__ import division
import time
import csv
import serial
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

# [angry, happy, sad]
emotion = [0,0,0]

# [R,G,B]
owe = "Nothing"
blinking = 0
BlinkIO = False
ecount = 0
mad = 0
sad = 0
happy = 0
love = 0
scared = 0
envy = 0
suprise = 0
off = (0,0,0)
cmad = (255,0,0)
csad = (0,255,0)
chap = (255,255,0)
clov = (255,0,255)
cscr = (255,255,255)
cenv = (0,255,0)
csup = (50,50,50)
omad = 0
osad = 0
ohap = 0
olov = 0
oscr = 0
oenv = 0
osup = 0
# number of times colour has been logged
count = 0

# delay between each log
delay = 60
blinkDelay = 1
# sets timer
timeout = time.time() + delay
blinktimer = time.time() + blinkDelay
#Boolean value for if Arduino is connected
connected = False

#Serial connection setup
ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)

# Twitter API setup
TRACK_TERM = "i love you, i love her, i love him, all my love,i'm in love,i really love,happiest,so happy,so excited, i'm happy,woot,w00t,wow,O_o,can't believe,wtf,unbelievable,i hate,really angry,i am mad,really hate,so angry,i wish i,i'm envious,i'm envious,i'm jealous,i want to be,why can't i,i'm so sad,i'm heartbroken,i'm so upset,i'm depressed,i can't stop crying,i'm so scared, i'm really scared, i'm terrified,i'm really afraid,so scared"


# KEEP SECRET
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = ''

api = TwitterAPI(
    CONSUMER_KEY,
    CONSUMER_SECRET,
    ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# Emotion algorithm
def send (emotion):
    serialColour = ','.join(map(str,off))
    ser.write(serialColour.encode())
    print "sent off"
    time.sleep(0.1)
    serialColour = ','.join(map(str,emotion))
    serv = serialColour.encode()
    print serv
    ser.write(serv)
    print "Sent once"
    time.sleep(1)
    ser.write(serv)
    print "Sent twice"
def sendBlink(emotion):
    serialColour = ','.join(map(str,emotion))
    ser.write(serialColour.encode())
def percentage(mood):
    output1 = mood / ecount
    output2 = output1 * 100
    output3 = int(output2)
    print output3
    return output3
def Calc_Change(per,old):
    if per == 0 and old == 0:
        print 0
        return 0
    elif old == 0 and per >= 0:
        print per
        return per
    elif per < old:
        out1 = old / per
        out = out1 - out1 - out1
        print out
        return out
    else:
        out = per / old
        print out
        return out
def ColorCalc(emotion,colorval):
    global color
    global BlinkIO
    if emotion >= 2:
        BlinkIO = True
        color = colorval
        print "Large change detected"  
        return True

    else:
        BlinkIO = False

        return False

#MAIN PROGRAM
emo = (csup)
send(emo)
value = ser.read(11,5)
print value
time.sleep(2)
send(off)
r = api.request('statuses/filter', {'track': TRACK_TERM})

for item in r: # for each tweet
    if time.time() > blinktimer and BlinkIO == True:

        print blinking
        if blinking == 0:
            blinking = 1
            send(color)
            print "blink on"
        elif blinking == 1:
            blinking = 0
            send(off)
            print "blink off"
    blinktime = time.time() + blinkDelay
    if time.time() > timeout: # If time elapsed
        print "Percentages"
        pmad = percentage(mad)
        psad = percentage(sad)
        phap = percentage(happy)
        penv = percentage(envy)
        psup = percentage(suprise)
        pscr = percentage(scared)
        plov = percentage(love)
        print "Change"
        fmad = Calc_Change(pmad,omad)
        fsad = Calc_Change(psad,osad)
        fhap = Calc_Change(phap,ohap)
        fenv = Calc_Change(penv,osad)
        fsup = Calc_Change(psup,osup)
        fscr = Calc_Change(pscr,oscr)
        flov = Calc_Change(plov,olov)
        emotions = {'mad' : fmad, 'sad' : fsad, 'happy' : fhap, 'envy' : fenv, 'suprise' : fsup, 'scared' : fscr, 'love' : flov}
        we = max(emotions,key=emotions.get)
        print "the world's mood is: " + we
        if we == owe:
            print "Same emotion"
        else:
            if we == 'mad':
                blinkI = ColorCalc(fmad,cmad)
                if blinkI == False:
                    send(cmad)

            elif we == 'sad':
                blinkI = ColorCalc(fsad,csad)
                if blinkI == False:
                    send(csad)

            elif we == 'happy':
                blinkI = ColorCalc(fhap,chap)
                if blinkI == False:
                    send(chap)

            elif we == 'envy':
                blinkI = ColorCalc(fenv,cenv)
                if blinkI == False:
                    send(cenv)

            elif we == 'suprise':
                blinkI = ColorCalc(fsup,csup)
                if blinkI == False:
                    send(csup)
            elif we == 'scared':
                blinkI = ColorCalc(fscr,cscr)
                if blinkI == False:
                    send(cscr)
            elif we == 'love':
                blinkI = ColorCalc(flov,clov)
                if blinkI == False:
                    send(clov)
        owe = we
        omad = pmad
        osad = psad
        ohap = phap
        oenv = penv
        osup = psup
        oscr = pscr
        olov = plov
        love = 0
        scared = 0
        suprise = 0
        sad = 0
        mad = 0
        happy = 0
        envy = 0
        ecount = 0
        timeout = time.time() + delay #resets timer

    #Manipulates tweet to add to emotion counter    
    leitem = item['text'] if 'text' in item else item # select tweet text

    if ('i hate' or 'really angry' or 'i am mad' or 'really hate' or 'so angry') in leitem: # if tweet contains angry
        mad += 1
        ecount += 1
        print "mad"
    if ('happiest' or 'so happy' or 'so excited' or "i'm happy" or 'woot' or 'w00t' )in leitem: # if tweet contains happy but not 'not happy'
        happy += 1
        ecount += 1
        print "happy"
    if ("i'm so sad" or "i'm heartbroken" or "i'm so upset" or "i'm depressed" or "i can't stop crying") in leitem: 
        sad += 1 # add 1 to sad count
        ecount += 1
        print "sad"
    if ('i love you' or 'i love her' or 'i love him' or 'all my love' or "i'm in love" or 'i really love') in leitem:
        love += 1
        ecount += 1
        print "Love"
    if ('wow' or 'O_o' or "can't believe" or 'wtf' or 'unbelieveable') in leitem:
        suprise += 1
        ecount += 1
        print "suprise"
    if ('i wish i' or "i'm envious" or "i'm jealous" or 'i want to be' or "why can't i") in leitem:
        envy += 1
        ecount += 1
        print "envy"
    if ("i'm so scared" or "i'm really scared" or "i'm terrified" or "i'm really afraid" or "so scared") in leitem:
        scared += 1
        ecount += 1
        print "scared"




ser.close()
```

Arduino code:

```
byte Red = 6;
byte Blue = 9;
byte Green = 3;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(Red,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Blue,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Green,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  analogWrite(Red,0);
  analogWrite(Blue,0);
  analogWrite(Green,0);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    String string = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');

    int comma1 = string.indexOf(',');
    int comma2 = string.indexOf(',');
    int none = string.indexOf('\n');
    String first = string.substring(0,comma1);
    String second = string.substring(comma1 + 1,comma2);
    String third = string.substring(comma2 + 1, none);

    int r = first.toInt();
    int g = second.toInt();
    int b = third.toInt();

    Serial.print(string);
    analogWrite(Red,r);
    analogWrite(Green,g);
    analogWrite(Blue,b);
  }
}
```

All this code is edited from other code or based off it so there is comments that don't mean anything much on the python program
Also, I need this project to be finished by arduino day (april 1st)
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: just tested to see what would happen if i swapped around send values sent to g and b. The led didn't light up the blue one and i sent 50,50,50

Comment: So i edited the arduino code to send me back what it recieves and the values that the arduino gets from it. It recieves 50,50,50, but for some reason the values it gets are, seperated by spaces: 50 , 50, Now i am so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake. I had the second comma index be exactly where the first one was (oops) in the arduino code